# Z3 get-answer returns unsupported

Tags: z3, z3-fixedpoint

I'm using the fixedpoint engine in Z3 to encode several universal horn formulas. The query turns out to be unsat. In Z3Py, using get_answer() returns the valuations to the uninterpreted relations. However, in the SMTLIB2 format, get-answer returns `unsupported`. Here's my program:

```
(declare-var x Int)
(declare-var y Int)

(declare-rel I (Int) interval_relation)
(declare-rel I1 (Int) interval_relation)
(declare-rel err (Int) interval_relation)

(rule (=> (= x 0) (I x) ))
(rule (=> (and (= y (+ x 1)) (I x) ) (I1 y) ))
(rule (=> (and (> y 2) (I1 y)) (err y) ))

(query (err y)
    :engine pdr
:use-farkas true
:print-answer true
)
(get-answer)
```

The output I am getting using Z3 `version 4.3.2` is:

```
unsat
unsupported
; get-answer
```

In Z3Py, creating a fixedpoint context `fp=Fixedpoint()`, and then executing `print fp.get_answer()` would return the valuations to `I`, `I1` and `err`. Is there a way of obtaining the same in SMTLIB2 format? 
Thanks.

Comment: Ah...get-answer is not part of SMTLIB2. I was making the mistake of assuming it is, since it's a part of Z3Py.

Comment: BTW, `declare-rel`, `rule` and `query` are also not part of SMTLIB2. These are Z3 specific commands for using the fixedpoint engines available in Z3.

Answer (score 0):

The comment section essentially answers the question.
The SMT-LIB2 extension for "query" takes attributes like your example illustrates.
In fact :print-answer amounts to getting the answer.